# Read & Write Data from Excel: POI & JXL | Found Exception org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, import-from-excel

I followed a tutorial to read data from excel & I succeeded. I used to find specific word/string in hundreds of urls using this code. Code is working **fine**. Only 1 issue is this that I am also getting an **exception**. I don't know why? Can anyone please help me to resolve exception in following code?

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ExcelDataReading {

    public void readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws IOException{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\Chrome latest driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String body = "";
        File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook guru99Workbook = null;
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
        guru99Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
}
        else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){
        guru99Workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
}
        Sheet guru99Sheet = guru99Workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        int rowCount = guru99Sheet.getLastRowNum()-guru99Sheet.getFirstRowNum();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
        Row row = guru99Sheet.getRow(i);

         int j=0; 
          do{
            String[] urls = new String[] {row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()};

            driver.navigate().to((String) urls[j]);
            body = driver.getPageSource();

            if(body.contains("text1") || body.contains("text2")) {
            System.out.println(""+ driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }

        j++;
    }while(j < row.getLastCellNum());

        }
}

        public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException{

        ExcelDataReading objExcelFile = new ExcelDataReading();
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\newpackage";
        objExcelFile.readExcel(filePath,"ExportExcel.xlsx","ExcelGuru99Demo");

        }
    }
```

But I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'BILAL-SHAHZAD', ip: '192.168.235.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59090}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c0e58f70a6f0740268535452b58fee91
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:857)
    at newpackage.ExcelDataReading.readExcel(ExcelDataReading.java:94)
    at newpackage.ExcelDataReading.main(ExcelDataReading.java:133)
```

Anyone help me please.

Comment: I think you need to add getcelltype validation steps.Sometimes  excel may consider URL as hyperlink.So try to add below steps:sheet.getrow(1).getcell(1).getcelltype() check cell type and if its none of this list{string,boolean,number,formula} then use this sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getHyperlink(); instead of getStringcellValue().Hope this helps.

Comment: @AmrutaPande Very Thanks for your reply!
Bro I did nothing & just run my script after one day and resolved. No more exception now .. hahahahaha
I faced exception for only 1-2 days, don't know why & how because I am newbie in selenium java.. But thanks God exception resolved automatically.